# Which enemy abilities are affected by silence?

Tags: torchlight-2

Torchlight 2 has many status effects that can be applied to monsters.  However, they seem to be poorly documented (if at all.)  One of these is `silence`, which has a spell dedicated to it, is a byproduct of the nether imp's attack, and is an effect produced by many magical weapons.

Its official spell description is this:

> Silences enemies within 8 meters, preventing them from using most skills.

**Which abilities/monsters are affected?** (The only one that I think I've noticed is the basilisk's immobilizing gaze.)

Comment: Pretty sure it's any active skill used by enemies. Basically, any kind of action that is not their default attack.

Comment: Hmm, but I've seen non-basic attacks still used after I've silenced enemies.  I don't think that's entirely correct.

Answer (score 2):

Silence is not dependent on enemies, instead it is dependent on the Skills. Some skills can be silenced and some can't be silenced.
There is a flag in the game files for the abilities which can be silenced.

By looking at some .dat files you can see which abilities can be silenced.

Example: The Basalisks in Act II. They have two skills. Basalisk Gaze and Firebreath. Firebreath has "CAN_BE_SILENCED:false" in the .dat, so this skill can't be silenced and they are going to use it against you even if you cast silence.

[Runic Forums](http://forums.runicgames.com/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=53611/)

Comment: This is excellent.  With your permission, I will modify your answer to include a sample of these silence-able abilities as I read them from the `.dat` files.  I will then accept your answer.  +1

Comment: Sure. why not. :)

Comment: Creating that list will take a long time, so it will take me a while to get around to it.  Hopefully it'll happen someday!